# Printing the contents of a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

The point of this program is to read characters from a txt file and store them into a 2D array. After this has been accomplished, the information is to be printed in the same manner it is read from in the txt file.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("sampleMaze.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        Maze maze = new Maze(s);
        System.out.print(file);
    }
}

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Maze {

    public int width;
    public int height;
    public Square [] [] sampleMaze;

    Maze(Scanner file) {
        this.width = Integer.parseInt(file.next());
        this.height = Integer.parseInt(file.next());
        this.sampleMaze = new Square [height] [width];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++) {
            String s = file.next();

            for (int j = 0 ; j < width ; j++) {
                sampleMaze[height][width] = Square.fromChar(s.charAt(j));
            }

        }
        System.out.print(sampleMaze[height][width]);
    }

}

public enum Square {
    WALLS("#"),
    OPEN_SPACES("."),
    START("o"),
    FINISH("*");

    String x;

    Square(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return x;
    }

    public static Square fromChar(char x) {
        if (x == '#')
            return WALLS;
        else if (x == '.')
            return OPEN_SPACES;
        else if (x == 'o')
            return START;
        else if (x == '*')
            return FINISH;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

And this is the error I am receiving when trying to accomplish the goal of the project:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "############"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Maze.<init>(Maze.java:15)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

Anyone know what's going on here and how I can correct this??

(This is what is in the sampleMaze.txt file) What I need for it to do is print like this:

```
############
#.#........#
#.#.######.#
#.#....#...#
#.###.*#.#.#
#...####.#.#
#.#.#..#.#.#
#.#.#.##.#.#
#o#......#.#
```

Comment: when you are parsing the int for your width and height it is trowing a NumberFormatException, that means whatever it is reading from the file isnt an int to be parsed

Comment: More specifically, it is the string "############", suggesting the width and height are missing from the input file.

Comment: So I should be writing the code as such:

 this.width = Character.parseChar(file.next());
 this.height = Character.parseChar(file.next());

Comment: you should post the txt files contents, and another thing your for loop is populating the same dimentions in the array every cycle, i think that is going to mess you up to

Comment: As the exception clearly says, you are trying to convert the string "############" into an int which raises a NumberFormatException. Please post your txt file to actually see what you are reading from it.

Comment: I have edited the main post and added the contents of the txt file that I need stored in the 2D array and then printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the width/height in the file, that method could work with a little tweaking. You could make the first two lines of the file contain the width and height of the maze, and use `parseInt(file.nextLine())` instead of `parseInt(file.next())`. An input file could look like this:

```
12
9
############
#.#........#
#.#.######.#
#.#....#...#
#.###.*#.#.#
#...####.#.#
#.#.#..#.#.#
#.#.#.##.#.#
#o#......#.#
```

and the code, instead of

```
this.width = Integer.parseInt(file.next());
this.height = Integer.parseInt(file.next());
```

would be

```
this.width = Integer.parseInt(file.nextLine());
this.height = Integer.parseInt(file.nextLine());
```

A much better way to get the width and height would be to determine them from the file's actual dimensions (Note: including the dimensions at the top of the input file for this method would mess things up). Instead of passing in a Scanner to `Maze`'s constructor, pass in the File itself. Then, set `width = new Scanner(file).nextLine().length()` and `height = file.length()`, where `file` isn't the Scanner, but the File itself. Then set `scanner = new Scanner(file)` and use that for the rest of the method.

Comment: So I changed my constructors to how you have mentioned, but I am honestly confused on what you're trying to say in your last paragraph. I'm pretty new when it comes to learning programming, so I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to accomplish this task.

Comment: I could have phrased that better. To get the width, you make a new Scanner ofer the file, and get the first line of the file. Then, you simply get the length of that string. To get the height, call the length() method of the File, which returns the number of lines in a file

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Array : ");
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", <your array>));
```